# Welcome email to include discount code for subscribers

Tags: magento

The environment is Magento 1.7.

Basically what I want to achieve is when users subscribes to the newsletter, the system automatically include a discount code in their welcome email. This discount code is for one time use for per account.

Searched around and found a tutorial which is best suit my requirement. Based on my understanding on that [tutorial](http://www.drewgillson.com/blog/send-discount-code-subscribers-newsletter/), we need to fetch some values out of the module configuration and user the helper to send an email with a coupon code.

On top of the codes I've made some amendments:

### 1)

**in the file**

```
app\code\core\Mage\Newsletter\controllers\SubscriberController.php
```

**before**

```
$this->_redirectReferer() in newAction()
```

**insert**

```
$helper = Mage::helper(‘subscribereward’);
$promo_value = Mage::getStoreConfig(‘subscribereward/promocode/dollarvalue’);
$promo_min = Mage::getStoreConfig(‘subscribereward/promocode/minpurchase’);

$helper->addPromoCode($email, $promo_value, $promo_min);
```

### 2)

**in the file**

```
app/code/community/Dg/Pricerulesextended/etc/config.xml
```

**replace**

```
Pricerulesextended/Observer
```

**with**

```
Dg_Pricerulesextended_Model_Observer
```

I've followed the steps but still can't get it working. Anybody care to shed a light?

Comment: Since this is Magento, what specifically isn't working? What happens?

Comment: the code simply doesn't work,  using the code above I can see the settings in my admin panel but no rules or coupon created.

Answer (score 0):

Aheadworks has an extension called Follow Up Email, and it does exactly that. Ive set it up for clients where when a customer signs up (or a number of actions) it sends a welcome email with a randomly generated coupon (or standard one).

Also what you could do is just make a coupon code and add it to a welcome email template. Just make a new transactional email and add the coupon to the template. No custom coding required at all.

Comment: hi that's a good suggestion, if I want to include a random generated coupon in the welcome email template how does the code goes?

Comment: also the first user who received the discount code will be able to pass around that "subscriber reward code" to other non subscriber as I can't define the groups in Magento..